# Will we lose features when dba.se leaves beta?

Tags: discussion

It might be my imagination but the user experience seems better here on dba.se than on SO and other non-beta sites. Editing questions and adding tags are two examples where we seem to have a more advanced interface:

[image]

Are these beta-only features or will we take them with us when we launch?

Comment: see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58587/reputation-requirements-compared

Comment: er... that's not what I'm asking about - see edit :)

Comment: Actually that is what you're asking. You don't lose any "features" of the site. Everything runs on one bit of software, and they add things all the time. Unless _everyone_ loses those features, you won't lose anything here. However, during the private beta you get access to a lot of stuff that you don't have on the public beta, per-se, but that's different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the tag interface is just a roll-out issue.  StackExchange.com has the feature, so I would expect dba.stackexchange.com to keep it after leaving beta.

Comment: It was, you're correct.

Answer (score 4):

When you leave Private Beta, you will only lose the following elements of your site:

- The old reputation tiers will be shifted over to the graduated site tiers. Which are much steeper than the Beta phase.
- You will lose the "Sketchy" theme in favor of the new theme that Jin will design for you.
- You will lose the "Site Stats" and "Help Us Grow This Site" banners on the right sidebar of the homepage and similar pages. These will be replaced by your normal adspace, which will rotate between new Area 51 proposals, interesting questions on the network, and community ads posted here on your Meta. This is because the Site Stats and Growth banners are intended solely for the promotion during beta.

Everything else - all functionality and mechanical systems, will remain the same. There is no true "loss" of features in graduation - it's something you should be looking forward to, after all. ♪

Answer (score 0):

Everything [has been revealed](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/improved-tagging/)